Prove that $g\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ when $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, $1\leq p<+\infty$, and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.
Background Information
Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, where $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Let $p$ satisfy $1\leq p<+\infty$ and let $q$ be defined by $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Let $F$ be an arbitrary element of $(L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu))^*$.
Notation$\quad$ Suppose that $B$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$. Let $\mathscr{A}_B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ consisting of those subsets of $B$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$. Let $\mu_B$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathscr{A}_B$. If $f$ is a real- or complex-valued function on $B$, then we will denote by $f'$ the function on $X$ that agrees with $f$ on $B$ and vanishes outside $B$. The formula $F_B(\langle f\rangle)=F(\langle f'\rangle)$ defines a linear functional $F_B$ on $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$. In this post I have shown that this functional satisfies $\|F_B\|\leq\|F\|$.
Now let $\{B_k\}$ be a sequence of disjoint sets that belong to $\mathscr{A}$, have finite measure under $\mu$, and satisfy $X=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k$. We know that there is for each $k$ a function $g_k$ in $\mathscr{L}^q(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ that represents $F_{B_k}$ on $L^p(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ and satisfies $\|g_k\|_q\leq\|F_{B_k}\|$. Define $g$ on $X$ so that it agrees on each $B_k$ with $g_k$.

My Question
I want to prove that $g\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.

What I Have Tried So Far

We know that for each $k$ there is a function $g_k$ in $\mathscr{L}^q(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ such that for each $\langle f_k\rangle\in L^p(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ we have $$F_{B_k}(\langle f_k\rangle)=\int f_kg_kd\mu_{B_k}$$ and that $\|g_k\|_q\leq\|F_{B_k}\|$. We can write $g$ as $g=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g_k\chi_{B_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g'_k$. We want to prove that $g\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.
Suppose first that $q<+\infty$. Then we want to show that $|g|^q$ is integrable; that is
$$
\int|g|^qd\mu = \int\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g'_k\right|^qd\mu < +\infty.
$$
Since for each $k$ we have $g_k\in\mathscr{L}^q(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ and $\int|g_k|^qd\mu_{B_k}=\int|g'_k|^qd\mu$, it follows that
$$
\int|g'_k|d\mu = \int|g_k|^qd\mu_{B_k} < +\infty,
$$
so $g'_k\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$. Note that we can write $g'_k=g_k\chi_{B_k}$.

I got stuck here, and I don't really know what to do next. I tried to use Beppo-Levi's Theorem as the following, but I didn't get anywhere:

\begin{align*}
\int\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g'_k\right|^qd\mu &= \int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g'_k|^qd\mu\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int|g'_k|^qd\mu\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int|g'_k|^qd\mu\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int\sum_{k=1}^n|g'_k|^qd\mu.
\end{align*}
(Note that $\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g'_k\right|^q=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g'_k|^q$ because the $B_k$'s are disjoint.)

Neither did I successfully showed that $g$ is bounded, which would then means $g\in\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.
Could someone please help me with the proof? Thank you very much in advance!

Appendix
Beppo Levi's Theorem$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ be an infinite series whose terms are $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. Then
\begin{align*}
    \int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_kd\mu = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int f_kd\mu.
\end{align*}

Using continuity of $F$, it should be straightforward to show $F(f) = \int f g,d\mu$ for all $f \in L^p(\mu)$. Hence $g = F$. Then theorem 6.14 of "Real Analysis" by G. Folland yields $|g|_{L^q} = |F|$.

Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^ng_k$ represents $F_{\cup_{k=1}^nB_k}$, so $\sum_{k=1}^n\lVert g_k\rVert_q=\lVert\sum_{k=1}^ng_k\rVert_q\leq \lVert F_{\cup_{k=1}^nB_k}\rVert \leq\lVert F\rVert$. Therefore $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lVert g_k\rVert_q<\infty$ and we get that $g\in L^q$.

Thank you very much for your answer! I think there might be a small issue: I think $\sum_{k=1}^n|g_k|q$ is not necessarily equal to $|\sum{k=1}^ng_k|q$. Moreover, all we need is to show $|\sum{k=1}^ng_k|_q<+\infty$. Right?

Hi! $\sum_{k=1}^n\lVert g_k\rVert_q=\lVert\sum_{k=1}^ng_k\rVert_q$ because the supports of the $g_k$ are disjoint. What we want to show is that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k$ is in $L^q$. This is because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lVert g_k\rVert_q<\infty$.

I worked out all the details based on @leoli1's answer. I post it here for my own reference. If you find any mistake, or if you would like to improve it (to make it more concise or to propose an easier proof, etc.), please leave a comment below. Thanks a lot for @leoli1's answer, and thank you in advance for future helpful comment!
Restate the Notation$\quad$ Suppose that $B$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$. Let $\mathscr{A}_B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ consisting of those subsets of $B$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$ (clearly, $B\in\mathscr{A}_B$; if a subset $B_1$ of $B$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}_B$, then $B_1\in\mathscr{A}$ and so $B_1^c\in\mathscr{A}$, which implies $B\backslash B_1=B_1^c\bigcap B\in\mathscr{A}$, and thus $B\backslash B_1\in\mathscr{A}_B$; if $\{B_i\}$ is a sequence of subsets of $B$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}_B$, then they all belong to $\mathscr{A}$ and so $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i\in\mathscr{A}$, which implies $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i\in\mathscr{A}_B$). Let $\mu_B$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathscr{A}_B$ (it is clearly a measure on the measurable space $(B,\mathscr{A}_B)$). If $f_B$ is a real- or complex-valued function on $B$, then we will denote by $f_B'$ the function on $X$ that agrees with $f_B$ on $B$ and vanishes outside $B$. The formula $F_B(\langle f_B\rangle)=F(\langle f_B'\rangle)$ defines a linear functional $F_B$ on $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$. Since (for $\langle f_B\rangle\in L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$)
\begin{align*}
    F_B(\langle f_B\rangle) &= F(\langle f_B'\rangle)\\
    &\leq \|F\|\cdot\|\langle f_B'\rangle\|_p\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\|f_B'\|_p\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\left(\int|f_B'|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\left(\int|f_B|^pd\mu_B\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\|f_B\|_{p,B}\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\|\langle f_B\rangle\|_{p,B},
\end{align*}
it follows that this functional satisfies $\|F_B\|_B\leq\|F\|$.
Restate the Question$\quad$ Now suppose that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and that $p$ satisfies $1\leq p<+\infty$. Let $\{B_k\}$ be a sequence of disjoint sets that belong to $\mathscr{A}$, have finite measure under $\mu$, and satisfy $X=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k$. According to the first part of this proof, there is for each $k$ a function $g_{B_k}$ in $\mathscr{L}^q(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ that represents $F_{B_k}$ on $L^p(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ (that is, for each $k$ there is a function $g_{B_k}$ in $\mathscr{L}^q(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ such that for each $\langle f_{B_k}\rangle\in L^p(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ we have $F_{B_k}(\langle f_{B_k}\rangle) = F(\langle f_{B_k}'\rangle) = \int f_{B_k}g_{B_k}d\mu_{B_k} = \int f_{B_k}'g_{B_k}'d\mu$) and satisfies $\|g_{B_k}\|_{q,B_k}\leq\|F_{B_k}\|_{B_k}$. Define $g$ on $X$ so that it agrees on each $B_k$ with $g_{B_k}$. We now check that $g\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ and that
\begin{align*}
    F(\langle f\rangle) = \int fgd\mu
\end{align*}
holds for each $\langle f\rangle$ in $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.
Proof$\quad$ Consider the measure space $\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k,\mathscr{A}_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k},\mu_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right)$. Let $f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\in\mathscr{L}^p\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k,\mathscr{A}_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k},\mu_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right)$ and $\left\langle f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right\rangle\in L^p\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k,\mathscr{A}_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k},\mu_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right)$. Since the $B_k$'s are disjoint, then $f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}$ shall be written as $\sum_{k=1}^nf_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}$ with each $f_{B_k}\in\mathscr{L}^p(B_k,\mathscr{A}_{B_k},\mu_{B_k})$ (note that here the domain of $f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}=\sum_{k=1}^nf_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}$ is $\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k$). Moreover, $f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}'=f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\left(f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\chi_{B_k}\right)$. Then
\begin{align*}
    F_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\left(\left\langle f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right\rangle\right) &= F\left(\left\langle f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}'\right\rangle\right)\\
    &= F\left(\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\chi_{B_k}\right)\right\rangle\right)\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^nF\left(\left\langle f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\chi_{B_k}\right\rangle\right)\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^nF\left(\left\langle\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}\right)\chi_{B_k}\right\rangle\right)\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^nF\left(\left\langle f_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}\right\rangle\right)\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^nF\left(\left\langle f_{B_k}'\right\rangle\right)\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^n\int f_{B_k}'g_{B_k}'d\mu\\
    &= \int\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf_{B_k}'g_{B_k}'\right)d\mu\\
    &= \int\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\chi_{B_k}g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\chi_{B_k}\right)d\mu\\
    &= \int f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\sum_{k=1}^n\chi_{B_k}d\mu\\
    &= \int f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}d\mu\\
    &= \int f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}'g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}'d\mu\\
    &= \int f_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}d\mu_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k},
\end{align*}
which implies that the function $g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}=\sum_{k=1}^ng_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}$ in $\mathscr{L}^q\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k,\mathscr{A}_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k},\mu_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right)$ represents $F_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}$ on $L^p\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k,\mathscr{A}_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k},\mu_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right)$. From the first part of the proof, we can conclude that $\left\|g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right\|_{q,\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\leq\left\|F_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right\|_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}$. But
\begin{align*}
    \left\|g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right\|_{q,\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k} &= \left(\int\left|g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right|^qd\mu_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
    &= \left(\int\left|g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^n}\chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right|^qd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
    &= \left(\int\left|g_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\chi_{B_k}\right)\right|^qd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
    &= \left(\int\left|\sum_{k=1}^ng_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}\right|^qd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
    &= \left\|\sum_{k=1}^ng_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}\right\|_q,
\end{align*}
so $\left\|\sum_{k=1}^ng_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}\right\|_q\leq\left\|F_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k}\right\|_{\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k} \leq \|F\| < +\infty$. Thus
\begin{align*}
    \left(\int|g|^qd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} &= \|g\|_q\\
    &= \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}\right\|_q\\
    &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\sum_{k=1}^ng_{B_k}\chi_{B_k}\right\|_q\\
    &< +\infty,
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
    \int|g|^qd\mu<+\infty,
\end{align*}
which implies $g\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.
